# for loop with try except while returning a list of outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, error-handling

```
def unik():
    edit_list = [(nested dictionary of values]
    
    prev_text=[]
    curr_text=[]
    for response_item in edit_list:
        
        try:
            
            revid = response_item['revid']
            article_title = response_item['title']
            pageid = response_item['pageid']
            
                        
            text = response['new']['pages'][str(pageid)]['revolutions']
            

            currwikitext = wiki_text[0]['slots']['main']['team'] 
            prevwikitext = wiki_text[1]['slots']['main']['team']
            

            curr_text.append(currtext)
            prev_text.append(prevtext)
            
            
            
        except:
            continue
    return prev_text, curr_text

unik()
```

this is a same of the code i having been working with. so this isthe problem:
edit_list is a series of nested dictionaries and list. i am trying to loop through this list with a try/except to avoid keyerror while appending these values in prev_text and curr_text lists as well as return v but i have been unable to do this, mainly because of the try/except(note I can not exclude try/except)

Comment: Why do you think that were you unable to use try/except in a loop? Because it looks like you are doing that.

Comment: what i meant is i cannot create and return the curr_text and prev_text because of the try/except

Comment: What is `wiki_text`? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the list you're iterating over. Is that supposed to be `text`?

Comment: Please add sample data and the desired result.